# CMSampleBufferCreate causes Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: swift, cmsamplebuffer

I am trying to make a CMSampleBuffer out of a CMBlockBuffer and I am using `CMSampleBufferCreate` but whatever I try I always get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

```
let status = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                              buffer, //CMBlockBuffer cannot be nil
                                              true,
                                              nil,
                                              nil,
                                              nil,
                                              1,
                                              0,
                                              nil,
                                              1,
                                              nil,
                                              &sampleBuffer //sampleBuffer is nil
)
```

I do not know how to do this so if there is another way or if I am doing something wrong please tell me because there are not many examples of this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it I needed to change it to:

```
let status = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                              buffer,
                                              true,
                                              nil,
                                              nil,
                                              nil,
                                              1,
                                              0,
                                              nil,
                                              0,
                                              nil,
                                              &sampleBuffer
)
```